# When should surf works and pcolor sholudn't?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a big complex array `v`. When I run `surf(abs(v))` I get a perfectly normal surface figure, even with colored height. Alas, when I try to run `pcolor(abs(v))` I get a black figure. When I slice `v` to be smaller, but as I enlarge the slice more and more the `pcolor` map grows darker, until it gets entirely black.

Should you find it necessary I can copy the code that creates `v`, I just didn't want to overload the massage.

Thanks
Amir

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without data to plot or an image showing the problem, but I'll have a go anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably just seeing the edges around the color pixels.

As [this answer points out](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/37049-removing-grid-edge-lines-in-pcolor-figure), the easy solution is to remove the edges. This is relatively easy:

```
h = pcolor(X,Y,C);
set(h, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

Comment: is it the same as `shading flat;`?

Answer (score 2):

Since `pcolor` gives You a 'checkboard' style of plot the lines separating neighboring elements can get too dense for high resolutions and shade the original picture. I'd suggest using `imagesc` instead:

```
% working example %
x = -1:0.0075:1;
[X Y] = meshgrid(x,x);
g = exp(-X.^2 - Y.^2);

close all
% can't see a thing with pcolor '
figure
pcolor(g)

% clear and pretty
figure 
imagesc(g)
```

if for some reason You wan't the griddy feel of it, check out `grid on` command on the `imagesc` picture.